# Getting 404 errors and more with sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, updates, ppa

I'm completely new to Linux.

Running Ubuntu 16.04.
When executing `sudo apt-get update` I get `404` errors and `Failed to fetch ...` along with a whole lot more. I do not know what this is nor how to fix it.

This is what it looks like:

```
Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/gtk3themes/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/gtk3themes/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Fetched 529 kB in 5s (95,5 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/gtk3themes/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_15.04  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A7D1D38BEB6D886
W: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_15.04  Release' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
5A7D1D38BEB6D886  
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/gtk3themes/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/gtk3themes/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 2):

These PPAs have been not updated to 16.04 yet. You can wait or disable them via `Updates`.

Comment: Ok, thanks! So this is nothing to be worried about at the moment?

Comment: No, if everything else works this is OK :)